# ChangeNotifierProxyProvider builder to create and update

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

This code was using an old provider I need to convert it to the latest ChangeNotifierProxyProver
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Like this above
My code :

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
        
          builder: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items,
          ),
        ),
```

Products class need 3 argument

```
Products(token, userId, listOfItems)
```

Now ChangeNotifierProxyProvider required to create, and update.
How to convert it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1tsp.png

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
  create: (_) => Products(previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
  update: (_, Auth auth, Products products) {
    products.authToken = auth.token;
    products.authUserId = auth.userId;
    return products;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the Products class takes three arguments, provide three empty arguments like this, while update takes the place of builder.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Products>(
      create: (ctx) => Products('', '', []),
      update: (ctx, auth, previousProducts) => Products(
          auth.token,
          auth.userId,
          previousProducts == null ? [] : previousProducts.items),
    ),
```